# When people talk about browser compatibility issue, is it refers to Browser API (DOM) or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When people talk about browser compatibility issue, 
is it refers to Browser API (DOM) or JavaScript?

Comment: Both. And more (e.g. CSS). But it depends on the context obviously… ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything.  CSS, parsing HTML, JavaScript API, bugs breaking things, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to *the browser*. Everything that *the browser* can interpret.